# Class D chopper

Tags: power-electronics

I am studying class D choppers. When both switches are turned on simultaneously, current flows from source to load in the same direction, as shown in figure below, so we get a positive current and a positive voltage. When both switches are turned off at the same time, how are those two diodes getting forward biased?
I know that when the anode is more positive than the cathode a diode is forward biased.

[image: class D chopper]

Comment: I’m puzzled by the presence of ‘E’. Why another power source? And why SCRs in this day and age (except if super high voltage).

Comment: @Kartman I suppose the load is an electric motor, and E represents the electromotive force.

Answer (score 2):

> *When both switches are turned off at the same time, how are those two
> diodes getting forward biased?*

I've de-cluttered your diagram to make things easier to see. Both devices active with the blue arrows representing current flow: -

[image]

The inductor builds up current and stored energy until such time when the devices deactivate: -

[image]

The stored energy in the inductor forces current (in the same direction) to pass through the only feasible path until the magnetic stored energy is depleted or, the devices become active again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But diode gets forward bias when anode is supplied with positive and cathode is supplied with negative voltage. Carrying this concept on mind I'm finding difficult how these diodes get forward bias when inductor gets discharged. As we can see that upper diode's cathode is connected to positive side of source voltage, how this diode conducts? If I'm lacking some concepts please let me know.

Comment: @RajeshRaskoti the stored energy in the inductor reverses its terminal voltage when the switches are disabled. The whole voltage across the inductor switches polarity to ensure that current continues to flow until all the magnetic energy is depleted or the switches become active again. Inductors do this automatically (called back-emf).

Comment: @RajeshRaskoti if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

from https://electricalbaba.com/class-d-or-type-d-chopper-explained/
You should use this schematic ... (ON or OFF on command).

[image]

It is easy to switch **ON** an **SCR**, but a bit difficult to switch it **OFF** ...
You need for this a special circuit or ... a sinusoidal source.
Some firing angles added.

[image]

[image]

[image]

General switches used ...

[image]